# Shrink failed in windows 10 due to The last unmovable file appears to be: \$BitMap::$DATA

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-space

I am using Windows 10 OS and  have 800gb of free space in Volume C: of my 1TB Hard disk. i only have C: drive and a recovery drive. I am trying to do a partition but it's failing due to unmovable files.

1. chkdsk has been run- no issues
2. error checking - no erros
3. Cleanup disk - done
4. defragment - done - 0% fragmented
5. finally triggered Shrink- -  shrink upto 800gb of free space available -  triggere for 300gb  but **failed due to many reasons**

First i encountered System Volume information for which i turned off System restore , then hibernate then internet files -  which are taken care of.
but now i  get the error : 
**The last unmovable file appears to be: \$BitMap::$DATA**

How could i resolve this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try using a 3rd party defrag program.

Comment: is that the only option i have @David ?

Comment: If you Google for "The last unmovable file appears to be: \$BitMap::$DATA" it would appear so ...